# Does anyone know of a C/C++ Unix QR-Code library?

Tags: c++, c, qr-code

I'm looking for a QR-Code library for C/C++, not Java or .Net please. Anyone knows of one?

Note: There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231741/qr-code-2d-barcode-coding-and-decoding-algorithms) a while back however but it didn't get 
answered properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How is this one?

http://megaui.net/fukuchi/works/qrencode/index.en.html

Comment: New link is http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/index.en.html

Comment: You might also find https://github.com/digdog/qrencode interesting

Comment: Great for encoding...doesn't decode :(

Comment: Might I suggest https://github.com/nayuki/QR-Code-generator

Answer (score 5):

The [zxing library](http://code.google.com/p/zxing) is primarily Java, but, includes a [port of the QR Code detector and decoder to C++](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/#svn/trunk/cpp).

Comment: Hi @Sean Owen, can I know current status of ZXing & CPP? I see two things.. 1. an older version `zxing/cpp`(link in ZXing repo itself) & 2. another repo from `glassechidna/zxing-cpp`. Can you please tell what would be a good option?

Answer (score 4):

check out my widely cross platform C port of Psytec QR Image generator
https://github.com/swex/QR-Image-embedded