# What library should I use to get the data from a photo of a QR Code?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, qr-code

> Similar: [Does anyone know of a C/C++ Unix QR-Code library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304537/does-anyone-know-of-a-c-c-unix-qr-code-library)

I tried [libqrencode](http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/index.en.html) but apparently it's only able to generate a QR-Code. However, I need a library that reads the data from a photo of a printed QR-Code.

It must be a C, C++ or Objective-C library and it has to compile on BSD systems. On my platform, Java and .NET are not available.

What libraries can I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [libdecodeqr](https://github.com/josephholsten/libdecodeqr) , it doesn't seem to be updated for over a year but a Google search reveals that it still works.

Answer (score 2):

zxing (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) is probably the most well-known and used in a number of barcode/qr-code apps. The original/primary code is Java but it includes a C++ port that is pretty actively maintained, particularly for QR codes.

The C++ library does not (currently) have an encoder, but it sounds like you want a decoder.

Comment: I've been tinkering with this library and I've gotta say that it is amazingly fast at recognizing QR codes. It's much faster than the RedLaser app, but that may be because RedLaser is looking for multiple bar code types.

Comment: RedLaser actually uses zxing, though they also apparently have their own code: http://redlaser.com/Attribution.aspx. But if you're using the zxing demo code, I'm pretty sure by default it only has the qr decoder enabled, which definitely makes it faster. The 1D support in the C++ port isn't used as widely as the qr code and isn't maintained as well as the qr code (or the 1D codes in the java port).