# Is there a plugin/webservice to read QR codes

Tags: php, qr-code

I want to generate/read the data to/from a QR code. I don't want to develop a QR generator/reader of my own.

Are there any plugins/webservice etc which I can use readily at my website??

I'm using PHP.

Comment: Try this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231741/qr-code-2d-barcode-coding-and-decoding-algorithms

Answer (score 1):

We have used this:

http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

for a voucher system for a British newspaper. It works very well and has good documentation.

Comment: I also need to read/scan the data from a Code. The one you've given seems only for generating the code!!

Comment: Can you give more details about how you intend to use the QR codes. If you encode a UID into the URL contained within the QR code then user can use their prefered QR code reader which will link back to your site and you can identify the code by the unique ID.

Comment: It's a web application for mobile devices. The user uploads a QR code, the application reads the data, and the application do stuffs to the data!!