# C# QR bit array decode

Tags: c#, qr-code

I was wondering is there any libraries that can decode QR code bit array instead of image.
For eaxample:

```
{
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
    {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
    {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1},
    {0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
    {1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1},
    {0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1},
    {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1},
    {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1},
    {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0}
}
```

Would become "Hi".

I don't need any of the image functionality.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231741/qr-code-2d-barcode-coding-and-decoding-algorithms

Comment: I want the exact opposite. Given a QR code I want the bytes so that I can create my own  QR code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) to decode the bit matrix. However, you need to convert the **multidimensional integer array** to **jagged boolean array**. Just convert `'1'` to `'true'` and `'0'` to `'false'`. Execute the following (assuming you have referenced the correct library) to get the result.

```
bool[][] bData; //this should be the converted bit matrix
com.google.zxing.qrcode.decoder.Decoder dec = new com.google.zxing.qrcode.decoder.Decoder();
com.google.zxing.common.DecoderResult result = dec.decode(bData);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the presentation of [QrCode.Net](http://qrcodenet.codeplex.com/), it seems that it will do what you are looking for as one of its features is:

> Decoding QR code given as bit matrix

Comment: Project does not seem to have decoding implemented.