# Create 2D bit array from 100 x 100 QR Code

Tags: go, qr-code

Given a QR Code of dimensions 100 x 100, I need to make a 2D bit array (`array[100][100]` that will hold 1 or 0). To get a better idea of the array I am trying to make, [look at the array given in this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634982/c-sharp-qr-bit-array-decode).

After hours of searching, I found a function on [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/go-qrcode/source/browse/qrcode.go) that would appear to get the job done. The problem is that the code is given in a .go file, which my computer cannot open.

The ideal solution would either offer a solution in another language, or suggest the way I should go about using the code I found on Google Code.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You can open an `.go` file in any text editor (notepad for example), or view the file in your web browser (the link you've posted)

Comment: Not sure what you try to do. "Given a QR Code"; in what format? Png image? Printed on paper? The source you referred to is used for encoding QR's, not decoding.

Comment: The QR Code is given in the format of a PNG, and had encoded a URL that I know. ANisus, your solution would appear to work seeing as there are parameters for URL encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for encoding an url (or other text) to a QR code array and show a textual presentation of the 2D array, you can rather easily make a command line tool to do this in Go.
Below is a fully working example of such a tool using the go package you mentioned.

In order to compile it and run it, go to http://golang.org where you can find instructions on how to install  Go, install external libraries, and compile the tool:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "code.google.com/p/go-qrcode"
)

var (
    url   = flag.String("url", "", "Url to encode")
    level = flag.Int("level", 0, "Recovery level. 0 is lowest, 3 is highest")
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    if *level < 0 || *level > 3 {
        fmt.Println("Level must be between 0 and 3")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    qr, err := qrcode.New(*url, qrcode.RecoveryLevel(*level))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    printArray(qr.Bitmap())
}

func printArray(a [][]bool) {
    fmt.Println("{")
    for _, x := range a {
        fmt.Print("  {")
        out := ""
        for _, y := range x {
            if y {
                out += "1"
            } else {
                out += "0"
            }
            fmt.Print(out)
            out = ","
        }
        fmt.Println("}")
    }
    fmt.Println("}")
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Usage of qrarray.exe:
  -level=0: Recovery level. 0 is lowest, 3 is highest
  -url="": Url to encode
```

Comment: Please mention what is wrong with the answer if voting down, since it surely does work if the OP is trying to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  This question was perfect, and your answer was awesome.  I did add one line to force it to disable the border: qr.DisableBorder = true